# Read a file from byte a until byte b

Tags: file, sed, bigdata, head

I want to break a big file into to smaller files mainly.

I use stream because I do not want to keep the big file in my disk.

What I am looking it is something similar to:

```
sed -n 'a,bp,' #this uses lines in file while i want bytes
```

or:

```
cat filename|head -c a| tail -c (a-b)  # this way takes too long with big files
```

Comment: `man split` http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is an issue, and you are using large files, I think you would do better with a bigger block size in `dd`, like this

```
dd bs=$a skip=1 if=filename | dd "bs=$((b-a))" count=1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract from byte offset `a` to byte offset `b`, you can use the [`dd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) command:

```
dd bs=1 "skip=$a" "count=$(($b - $a))" if=filename
```

The quotes are optional.  The main problem to worry about is whether the shell arithmetic will handle offsets bigger than 31-bits (2 GiB).  Most likely it won't be an issue (for example, 64-bit Bash handles 12-digit numbers with ease on Mac OS X), but be cautious if you need to deal with really large files on 32-bit systems.  You could use `bc` instead of the built-in `$((…arithmetic…))` notation, if need be.